# Arranging tables in R

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I am working with the dataset twinData in R. I have two questions related to data wrangling.

How would I go about listing only the combinations of cohort and zygosity where the twins’ heights are significantly similar.

My prior code was to create a new variable to indicate whether the correlation coefficient between ht1 and ht2 in the particular subgroup is greater 0.5, with 95 percent confidence.

```
sig_twin_cor <- twinData %>%
  group_by(cohort,zygosity) %>%
  do(tidy( cor.test(~ ht1 + ht2, alternative = "greater" , data = . ))) %>%
  arrange(desc(estimate)) %>%
  mutate(Greater0.5 = ifelse(estimate>0.5,"Yes","No"))
sig_twin_cor
```

Second, I need to transform the dataset twinData into a narrow form using gather(). Can someone show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) for transforming dataset into wide or long format

Comment: From which package is `twinData` from?

Comment: Ronak Shah - The package is library(OpenMx).